# Strange issue with network interfaces on freshly re-built pc

Tags: networking, drivers, motherboard, connection

Ok, here goes. Just finished replacing the motherboard on my PC at home. I swapped it out no issues, the chipset on the old board was a Z170, replaced with a Z270.

Everything seems to work absolutely perfect, except for ANY network cards, which randomly (and intermittently) disconnect from whatever network they are connected to. My intuition tells me this is clearly a software issue.

So, I format and re-install W10 to solve the problem, figuring that was the best POA given the chipset change.

No dice. My ethernet randomly pops up to say no network/internet. To test the NIC, I decide to disable it and use a USB wifi dongle I have lying around. This installs and connects no problem, but then - the same. Random disconnects.

Now I am at a loss where to go next. To make sure it isnt a problem with the network in my house I have tethered the pc to my iphone, and the same problem also occurs there, so to sum it up, no matter what network card I use on the pc, or what network I connect to, it disconnects and has problems with the IP config. Im out of things to try - has anyone ever came across anything like this before?

My heart still says software - but how?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try update bios of motherboard, and reset bios to default settings. If you want test on different system, you can try a live cd.